# UWP List view items clear without calling clear method

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `ListView` into which I add items through code behind. When I'm trying to retrieve an item later, the `ListView` has no items remaining without calling the clear method.

I've filled the `ListView` with the following code:

```
private void SetupPageIndicators(int e)
{
    listView.Items.Clear(); // I clear it here then new items are added.
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Tag = i;
        btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        Ellipse el = new Ellipse
        {
            Tag = i,
            Height = 8,
            Width = 8,
            Margin = new Thickness(12),
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray),

        };
        btn.Tapped += Btn_Tapped;
        btn.Content = el;
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(btn, $"Page {i + 1}");
        listView.Items.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

I tried getting the items from `ListView` via `listview.items[selectedindex]` and animate the `ListViewItem` as follows:

```
private void AdjustIndicatorStackPanel(int selectedIndex)
{
    try
    {
        if (firstrun)
        {
            if (oldAnimatedButton != null)
            {
                Button oldbutton = null;

                oldbutton = oldAnimatedButton;
                Ellipse olderellipse = (Ellipse)oldbutton.Content;
                buttontoanimate = (Button)listView.Items[selectedIndex];
                if (oldAnimatedButton != buttontoanimate && buttontoanimate != null)
                {
                    ellipseToAnimate = (Ellipse)buttontoanimate.Content;
                    ellipseToAnimate.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { ScaleX = 1.7f, ScaleY = 1.7f };
                    olderellipse.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { ScaleX = 1, ScaleY = 1 };
                    ellipseToAnimate.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                    olderellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                            oldAnimatedButton = buttontoanimate;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count - 1; i++) // this was put in to test why i was getting nullexception error it turns it appears that listView.Items.count is actually = 0 here where it was greater then zero when items were added
                {
                    var za = (Button)listView.Items[i];
                    var b = za.Tag;
                }
                var a = listView.Items[selectedIndex];
                buttontoanimate = (Button)listView.Items[selectedIndex];
                ellipseToAnimate = (Ellipse)buttontoanimate.Content;
                ellipseToAnimate.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { ScaleX = 1.7f, ScaleY = 1.7f };
                ellipseToAnimate.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                oldAnimatedButton = buttontoanimate;
            }
            listView.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Analytics.TrackEvent("Crashed during updating selected page");
        Crashes.TrackError(e);
    }
}
```

After filling the `ListView`, I'm not calling `listView.Items.Clear()`, but somehow the listview's items are cleared.  It used to work.  I've removed the code, I've re-added it, but it is still empty.
The Github Repo is at https://github.com/IsaacMorris1980/appLauncher/tree/Fix_options_and_settings

Both of these functions are on the mainpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code you shared and the historical version of the project in GitHub, I compare the two project, you need to use the correct logic in function `AdjustIndicatorStackPanel`.
Only need to change one place.

```
  if (!firstrun)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought i had reverted all code changes this worked